# print RichTextBox

Tags: c#, printing, richtextbox

Set Picture

```
Image image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\a.jpg");
Clipboard.SetImage(image);
richTextBox1.Paste();
```

Text Print

```
PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog();
PrintDocument documentToPrint = new PrintDocument();
printDialog.Document = documentToPrint;
if (printDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    StringReader reader = new StringReader(richTextBox1.Text);
    documentToPrint.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(DocumentToPrint_PrintPage);
    documentToPrint.Print();
}


private void DocumentToPrint_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    StringReader reader = new StringReader(richTextBox1.Text);
    float LinesPerPage = 0;
    float YPosition = 0;
    int Count = 0;
    float LeftMargin = e.MarginBounds.Left;
    float TopMargin = e.MarginBounds.Top;
    string Line = null;
    Font PrintFont = this.richTextBox1.Font;
    SolidBrush PrintBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);

    LinesPerPage = e.MarginBounds.Height / PrintFont.GetHeight(e.Graphics);

    while (Count < LinesPerPage && ((Line = reader.ReadLine()) != null))
    {
        YPosition = TopMargin + (Count * PrintFont.GetHeight(e.Graphics));
        e.Graphics.DrawString(Line, PrintFont, PrintBrush, LeftMargin, YPosition, new StringFormat());
        Count++;
    }

    if (Line != null)
    {
        e.HasMorePages = true;
    }
    else
    {
        e.HasMorePages = false;
    }
    PrintBrush.Dispose();
}
```

This code only print text in richtextbox but
how can print text and image in the richtextbox?

Answer (score 0):

I think, you need rewrite function `DocumentToPrint_PrintPage` for render rtf to `e.Graphics` with text and images. Now, the function render only text from `RichTextBox.Text.`

You need read from `RichTextBox.rtf`, and parse it and draw it like `e.Graphics.DrawString` ([docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/19sb1bw6(v=vs.110).aspx)) for texts and `e.Graphics.DrawImage` ([docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/42807xh1(v=vs.110).aspx)) for images